# how to find alphabetic value of a keyword

Tags: python

I am currently trying to produce a program that allows me to encrypt and decrypt a words using a keyword, I have been told to use alphabetic value to do add from another words alphabetic value I know that I need to use `ord` or `chr` but I am not very confident in using this as I'm a beginner at programming, however I have no idea how to do this and would much appreciate, if someone could explain this to me with some examples.

Comment: I think you want `ord` and `chr`

Comment: thanks but im a beginner at python and I have no idea how to use these functions and would much appreciate if you can show me examples. thanks

Comment: `ord("A") -> 65` `chr(65) -> A`

Comment: If you look at the docs you will get all the info you need about either https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: could you please create an example program to show me how.

Comment: I added a simple example as an answer, the rest I will leave as an exercise for yourself.

Comment: what have you tried so far? please provide examples of desired output for given input. you can think of `ord` and `chr` as dual in the sense `encode` and `decode` are. for instance `'A' == chr(ord('A'))`

Comment: Please explain what you don't understand when you read the documentation for [chr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) and [ord()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord). It's not easy to figure out what part of it you have problems with.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "foo!#bar"


enc_key = "key"
# get sum of ord's  of letters in key modulo 256
sm_ords= sum(map(ord,enc_key)) % 256

  # add sum of ord's in encryption letter in key to ord of each char in s and use chr to create a new char 
enc = "".join(chr((sm_ords + ord(ch))) for ch in s)

# reverse the encryption using - ord
dec = "".join(chr((ord(ch) - sm_ords)) for ch in enc)


print(enc)
print(dec)

¯¸¸jl«ª»
foo!#bar
```

Answer (score 0):

This code encrypts / decrypts a string by adding the value of each of the keyword letters to each character in the string to be encrypted.

```
def encryptfunction():
    result = ""
    addedup = 0
    for letter in wordtoencrypt:
        for letter2 in keyword:
            addedup = addedup + ord(letter2)
        result = result + chr(ord(letter) + addedup)
    return result

def decryptfunction():    
    result = ""
    addedup = 0
    for letter in wordtoencrypt:
        for letter2 in keyword:
            addedup = addedup + ord(letter2)
        result = result + chr(ord(letter) - addedup)
    return result

wordtoencrypt = input("Enter the word to encrypt:")
keyword = input("Enter the keyword:")
encrypt = int(input("encrypt(1) or decrypt(0)"))

if encrypt == 1:
    print(encryptfunction())
else:
    print(decryptfunction())
```